# Is using akka in this way with sockets bad practice?

Tags: scala, akka

Here is how I configure ReactiveMongo with PLay! to accept WebSocket connections and return data via an Actor to the client :

```
@Singleton
class Cont @Inject() (implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer, val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)
    extends Controller with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {

  val collection: reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONCollection = reactiveMongoApi.connection.db("db1").collection("col1");

  def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef[String, String](out => ActorObj.props(out))
  }

  object ActorObj {

    def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new ActorClass(out))
  }

  class ActorClass(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case msg: String => {
        val queryDoc = BSONDocument("id" -> "1")
        val enumerator: Enumerator[BSONDocument] =
          collection.find(queryDoc).options(QueryOpts().tailable.awaitData).cursor[BSONDocument].enumerate()

        val processDocuments: Iteratee[BSONDocument, Unit] =
          Iteratee.foreach { doc =>

            out ! (String.valueOf(doc.getAs[Int]("auditCount").get))

          }
        enumerator.run(processDocuments)

      }

    }
  }
}
```

As I'm just creating one actor per client socket connection and using that same actor to send data via socket to client is using Akka in this way a bad practice ? The reason I think it's bad practice is that akka actors should be short lived but actors in this implementation will live as long as the socket is open so could be hours, days.....

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with long lived actors, can't say anything about the particulars about using the mongo api although `.awaitData` sounds suspiciously like something blocking.

Comment: @johanandren from http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.QueryOpts . .awaitData 'Toggles AwaitData: Block a little while waiting for more data instead of returning immediately if no data.'